# How can I centralise all click events in flutter to handle analytic events from single place?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need guidance on implementing functionality to centralise all click events in flutter. I am working on an application in which I am integrating Google Analytics events, so here when I try to capture data on different screen click events, on every screen I am calling the analytic event.

Instead of calling/writing those methods on every click, is there any way to centralise this logic? I want to centralise the logic of each and every click event.

Answer (score 2):

Clicks occur in completely different places in the application. and you processing them there. Main idea, you should use some kind of state management: inheritedWidget/provider/bloc/riverpod etc. And you should have one instance of you state management class, which will be responsible for calling analytics event, and will be available all over application.

e.g. For Cubit, every place where click occurs and it is needed, you will do something like this (eventType and someDataYourAnalyticsNeed you define as you need):

```
onTap: () {
  BlocProvider.of<AlalyticsCubit>(context).sendEvent(
    eventType, someDataYourAnalyticsNeed,
  );
}
```

And your cubit(choose any - inheritedWidget/provider/bloc/reverpod):

```
class AlalyticsCubit extends Cubit<AlalyticsState> {
   AlalyticsCubit(this.analytic) : super(InitialAlalyticsState();

   final YourGoogleAnalytic analytic;

   void sendEvent(
         EventType eventType, 
         Map<String, dynamic> someDataYourAnalyticsNeed,
       ) {
     analytic.sendEvent(eventType, someDataYourAnalyticsNeed);
  }
}
```

And on start:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => BlocProvider(
      create: (_) => AlalyticsCubit(YourGoogleAnalytic()),
      child: MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: AppTheme.themeData(),
          onGenerateRoute: _routeBuilder.onGenerateRoute,
        );
```